# if image is → on-error fetch image on the base of gender value

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fetch an image, and if on-error, get the default image based on the gender value.
pls advice How can I fetch an on-error default image on base of gender value ?

```
echo"
   
<img  src=".'imagefolder/'.$_row['img']."
   
<?php if (".$_row['gender']." != 'Male'):?>

onerror = this.src='female-default.jpg'

<?php else: ?>

onerror = this.src='male-default.jpg'

<?php endif; ?> 
   
>";
```

Comment: You can't have if/else blocks in the middle of an echo. Look into using a ternary instead

Comment: already added→ <?php else: ?>

Comment: That's still part of an if/else, which **you cannot have inside of an echo**. here is information on [ternary operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Though with your quotes, the PHP inside is actually being sent right to the browser instead of evaluated

Comment: i am a learner can you pls advice the correct way to fetch image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes mean that none of the PHP inside is being evaluated, and you can't use if/else blocks inside an echo anyway. You can break it apart

```
echo "<img  src='imagefolder/'" . $_row['img'] . "' ";

if ( $_row['gender'] != 'Male'):

echo "onerror = this.src='female-default.jpg'";

else:

echo "onerror = this.src='male-default.jpg'";

 endif;
   
echo ">";
```

or you can use a ternary

```
echo "<img src='imagefolder/{$_row['img']}'" . ($_row['gender'] != 'Male' ? " onerror = this.src='female-default.jpg'" : " onerror = this.src='male-default.jpg'") . ">";
```

Comment: oh really thanks its working fine ,,,, thanks a lot !!  i used this (or you can use a ternary ) thanks a lot !